# Parse arguments and convert it to DateTime in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

The user is able to determine the parameters of a query, such as:

```
StartTime
EndTime
ProductId
```

He can set any date to `StartTime` and `EndTime` but he also wants to refer the current date something like `StartTime=@Today`.

He also wants to add or substract days from it such as `StartTime=@Today-30` so when the query runs it will always select the last 30 days.

These parameters are processed by javascript code.
How would you parse these placeholders (`@Today`, `@CurrentMonth`, `@ThisWeek`, etc), convert them to DateTime and do calculations on them?

Comment: By "Today" you mean today, 0:00 am, or the whole day span till 12:00 pm?

Comment: By "Today" I mean "2013-07-12 00:00:00" but I don't care the time part, just the date part.

Comment: Just asking because somebody entering `EndTime=@Today` might expect result that end today…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regex to match them:

```
var date = input.replace(/@(Today|ThisWeek|CurrentMonth)([+-]\d+)?/, function(_, expr, days) {
    var curr = new Date();
    if (expr == "Today")
        curr.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // to Midnight
    else if (expr == "ThisWeek")
        curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - ((curr.getDay()+6) % 7)); // to Monday
    else if (expr == "CurrentMonth")
        curr.setDate(1); // to first of month
    else
        return "unknown keyword";
    if (days)
        curr.setDate(curr.getDate() + parseInt(days, 10));

    return formatDate(curr);
});

function formatDate(d) {
    return d.getFullYear()+"-"+("0"+(1+d.getMonth())).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+d.getDate()).slice(-2);
}
```

Comment: I tried the following inputs: `@Today`, `@Today - 30`, `@Today-30` but none of them worked. I believe the last one should work. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for testing, that should've been my work :-) I forgot the argument of the replacer function that takes the whole match (not only the capturing groups). Fixed answer, and [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y7YV/2/).

Comment: Okay, found it. The callback function's first parameter is the input, the second is the `Today` and the third should be the date. I'll keep testing it.

Comment: I prefer this solution to the DateJS plugin because it's simple, lightweight and can be customized in any way. Thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: Found another bug: missing parenthesis before `%` when parsing @ThisWeek: `curr.setDate(curr.getDate() - ((curr.getDay()+6) % 7));`

Answer (score 2):

[DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/), has some very powerful functions for parsing/manipulating dates. The following excerpt is from their homepage:

```
// What date is next thursday?
Date.today().next().thursday();

// Add 3 days to Today
Date.today().add(3).days();

// Is today Friday?
Date.today().is().friday();

// Number fun
(3).days().ago();

// 6 months from now
var n = 6;
n.months().fromNow();

// Set to 8:30 AM on the 15th day of the month
Date.today().set({ day: 15, hour: 8, minute: 30 });

// Convert text into Date
Date.parse('today');
Date.parse('t + 5 d'); // today + 5 days
Date.parse('next thursday');
Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

By using your own values, you will be able to write a program/function that will accomplish what you need using this library

Comment: This one looks amazing! I'll give a try!

Comment: It is a great plugin, however it can't handle my special cases, only "today". +1 anyway.